# How to get the number generated by CHECKSUM from a mysql table?

Tags: mysql, database, checksum

*MySql:* When I execute `CHECKSUM TABLE tablaa` gives the result:

`Table        | Checksum
prueba.tablaa | 1290260502`

If you notice, generate the number `1290260502`, *how can I get that number from a query?*

Thanks

Comment: I believe this question may have an answer you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33897469/select-and-return-only-checksum-not-table-from-checksum-table-in-mysql?rq=1

Comment: Hi @andrei, this solution does not serve me, because you must specify the columns of the table, I need it to be dynamic, just specifying the name of the table

Answer (score 1):

you can try this works fine

```
$query= "CHECKSUM TABLE prueba.tablaa";
$result= mysqli_query($con, $query);


while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
$value= $row['Checksum'];

echo $value;
```

Comment: Thank you, but I needed it in C#